# How I can count turtles with a certain variable in a patch with another variable?

Tags: netlogo

I'm having troubles with my monitors.
I want to count the total turtles with a certain variable in patches with another varible, but haven't been able to do it, all I got was erros.
Here is what I have:

```
 patches-own [inovations?]
 turtles-own [income]

   count turtles with [income > 800] on patches with [inovations? = TRUE]
```

Thank you

Comment: you can replace `[inovations? = TRUE]` with just `[inovations?]`, the additional `= TRUE` doesn't add any meaning

Answer (score 2):

A turtle always has access to the variables of the patch which it is on.  So you can just do:

```
count turtles with [income > 800 and inovations? = TRUE]
```

It's the same reason you can do things like `ask turtles [ set pcolor red ]` and `count turtles with [ pxcor = max-pxcor ]` even though `pcolor` and `pxcor` are patch variables.